# Simple cocoa calculator

Tags: cocoa, macos, operating-system

I'm in the process of teaching myself basic cocoa application development and so I'm stepping up to the classic "calculator" project.

What I was wondering is this: to create the actual calculator interface would it be best to just add 4 rows of 4 NSButton controls and edit them to have the label/functionality I want or is there a more efficient way to create the layout?

I know this is a basic application but following OS X rules I want my code to be as efficient as possible so I want to make sure I'm doing it right.

Thanks for any help guys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with creating 4x4 buttons and you'll have the most flexibility with this approach. The most efficient way though would be to use an NSMatrix. To create a matrix of buttons in Interface Builder, create one button (your prototype), then select Layout->Embed Objects in->Matrix from the menu. When you now select the matrix, you can specify 4 rows and 4 columns in the Attributes tab of the inspector window.

Comment: Thanks.  As long as individually creating the buttons won't create any type of inefficiency then I will probably do that.  The NSMatrix seems like a good idea, too, and I may use it later just to get the hang of it.  Thanks again for the tip!